# Is it correct to say "I am in the wrong"?

Tags: negation

as in "I assume to have good knowledge on his biography (example). But now I realize I am in the wrong."

Answer (score 2):

According to the [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/in-the-wrong), "in the wrong" means that you are responsible for something bad.

Generally speaking, you only use it about relatively minor wrongs, for example forgetting a friend's birthday or making somebody late for an appointment. Not having a complete knowledge of somebody's biography isn't really serious enough for this expression.

In this particular situation, I would say

> I assumed that I had good knowledge of his biography, but now I realize I was mistaken.

Comment: Or '...I was wrong'.